# How should staccatissimo be played?

Tags: piano, technique, terminology, articulation, interpretation

How should staccatissimo be played on Handel, Beethoven, and Liszt pieces? I have read that it is like staccato only shorter, but it seems like it is used when notes should be staccato *and* accented. Am I dreaming?

Comment: Generally staccato notes should be accented slightly anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it is accented and shorter. The notes should be extremely separated and distinct.